# Converting interval to numeric

Tags: r, numeric

The structure of my dataframe is this:

```
    'data.frame':   74 obs. of  7 variables:
$ Scientific_Name                           : Factor w/ 74 levels "Aesculus glabra",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ Endangered.or.threatened                  : int  0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0     ...
$ Lat_spread                                : num  12.95 1.22 13.18 11.23  15.74 ...
$ Restricted_range                          : int  0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 ...
$ Available                                 : int  1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 ...
$ Abiotic_adapted_not_including_availability: int  4 NA 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 4 ...
$ Dispersal_score                           : int  5 NA 2 2 9 2 4 1 5 4  ...
```

I am trying to make the integer columns into numeric vectors. And this is my code:

```
> RestrictedY <- subset(Status_restricted_Wilcox, Endangered.or.threatened == 1, select = Restricted_range)
> RestrictedY <- as.vector(RestrictedY)
> RestrictedY <- as.numeric(RestrictedY)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> Status_restricted_Wilcox <- read.csv("~/Documents/Honours_data_analysis/Status_restricted_Wilcox.csv", na.strings="NA_integer_")
>   View(Status_restricted_Wilcox)
> RestrictedY <- subset(Status_restricted_Wilcox, Endangered.or.threatened == 1, select = Restricted_range)
> RestrictedY <- as.vector(RestrictedY)
> RestrictedY <- as.numeric(RestrictedY)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

What am I doing wrong? My error comes out as a 'double' but I dont understand what the matter is. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `subset()`, you will always get a data.frame back unlike when you use other forms of subsetting which return a vector when you choose a single column. You cannot coerce a data.frame to an atomic numeric value. Try

```
RestrictedY <- subset(Status_restricted_Wilcox, Endangered.or.threatened == 1, select = Restricted_range)[[1]]
#or 
RestrictedY <- subset(Status_restricted_Wilcox, Endangered.or.threatened == 1)$Restricted_range)
# or
RestrictedY <- with(Status_restricted_Wilcox, Restricted_range[Endangered.or.threatened == 1])
```

You shouldn't need any further coercion since R is usually pretty good at converting integer to numeric when necessary.